# Data send in android real device

Tags: java, android, gps, device

I made a project based on GPS location retrive.

```
public class LbsGeocodingActivity extends Activity {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

protected LocationManager locationManager;

protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener()
    );

retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCurrentLocation();
        }
});        

}    

protected void showCurrentLocation() {

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}   

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

Here if I run it in emulator I need to send the lon and lat from emulator control:

[Emulator control](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html)

But I want to run it in my device. So when I run it it does not retrieve any lon ,lat. Any idea how I can send data in real device?

Comment: is your GPS on in the device ?

Comment: ya.Its GPS supported android device

Comment: I am not saying supported. In settings menu, you need to start the GPS Service, so it will show your a Satelite dish icon on the title bar

Comment: the gps icon show in device.But does not retrive any location lon,lat

Comment: ok fine, are you in office? for fetching GPS you need to be near window or outside below the open sky for first time.

Comment: oho...ya.i am in offic.Ok.wait.let me try in outside.

Comment: no.it does not work in outside.But in emulator it works fine

Comment: Please come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/)